# SRWebSocket handleMessage: _block_invoke getting freeze app, How to handle this issue?

Tags: ios, websocket

I have some records in server, when background to foreground the app server will send all the records and from client side i'm savings all data into coredata. But my app became frozen, and its working fine only after all updates and savings are done. I have found some line of code which takes too much time on deadlock

```
 SRWebSocket handleMessage: _block_invoke
```

I don't know how to handle this issue, please guide me 
profiler: https://www.dropbox.com/s/snjmob5akhcq865/Instruments6.trace.zip?dl=0

**websocket.h**

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SRWebSocket.h"
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
typedef enum _IXResponseTypes
{
eIXConnectToWebSocket=1,
eIXBindWithWebSocket
}
IXResponseType;
@protocol IXWebSocketDataManagerDelegate;

@interface IXWebSocketDataManager : NSObject<SRWebSocketDelegate>
+ (IXWebSocketDataManager*)sharedNetworkDataManager;
//@property (weak, nonatomic, assign) id<IXWebSocketDataManagerDelegate>    delegate;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) id<IXWebSocketDataManagerDelegate> delegate;

 @property (strong, nonatomic)SRWebSocket *webSocket;
 @property (assign, nonatomic)CFMutableBitVectorRef bitvec;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *selectedMessageArray;
 @property BOOL feedbackSaveIndicator;

 //@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SRWebSocketDelegate> delegate;

 - (void)connectWebSocket;
 -(void)closeWebSocket;
```

**websocket.m**

```
 - (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message
 {

 AppDelegate *sharedAppdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSLog(@"MESSAGE FROM WEBSOCKET==%@",message);


    NSDictionary *responseDict = [message JSONValue];



   if ([[responseDict allKeys] containsObject:@"body"])
        {
            //adding activity id
            NSString *strings = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",       [responseDict objectForKey:@"body"]];
            NSString *firstLetter = [strings substringToIndex:1];

            if ([firstLetter isEqualToString:@"{"]) {
                int responseCode=[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"code"] intValue];

                [self checkResponseCode:responseDict indexvalue:responseCode isArray:0];

            } else {
                NSArray *bodyDicta=[responseDict objectForKey:@"body"];

               // if (!sharedAppdelegate.flag) {


                for (int i=0; i<bodyDicta.count; i++) {
                    int responseCode=[[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"body"] objectAtIndex:i ] objectForKey:@"code"] intValue];

                    //Call your function or whatever work that needs to be done
                    //Code in this part is run on a background thread


                    //Stop your activity indicator or anything else with the      GUI
                    //Code here is run on the main thread



                    NSLog(@"Delaying");



                    [self checkResponseCode:[bodyDicta objectAtIndex: i] indexvalue:responseCode isArray:1];
                }
            }
              //  sharedAppdelegate.flag = YES;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you found any solution on that?